# Android "Hello World" tutorial using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I attempted to program my first app; "Hello World" and I already encountered a bug I cannot fix. When I run the program I get:

invalid command-line parameter: Files.
Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
please use -help for more information

Does anyone know what this means and how I can fix it?

Comment: This bug was introduced in the latest android sdk (ver 12). Tanmays answer below should fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main problem is you installed your android sdk in a path where there is a space in the address.If you install the sdk in "**C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk**",then you will surely get that issue.Try to use any directory which does not contain any space in it like **C:\Android\android-sdk**  .

Or try to run the AVD from the  command line like this **C:\Progra~1\Android\android-sdk**.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you Tanmay, Ahmet (and Rob)! I uninstalled from the default folder and then re-installed in root and everything works fine now.