# Getting error in starting Emulator

Tags: android

When I run my application, I am getting an error. The error is:

> invalid command-line parameter:
>   sw\android-sdk-windows\tools/emulator-arm.exe. Hint: use '@foo' to
>   launch a virtual device named 'foo'. Please use -help for more
>   information

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: It can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702587/android-hello-world-tutorial-using-eclipse/6702835#6702835

Comment: No, this doesn't help. I am giving the sdk path with no spaces. And some of my virtual devices are wrking and some are not. If i creare a new device then it works, but i cant make a new virtual device daily.

Comment: E:\Androidsw\android-sdk-windows

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21831/how-to-test-drive-google-android-on-your-pc-without-buying-a-phone/ take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your sdk path in eclipse contains "Program Files", which contains space. Instead of "Program Files" do it PROGRA~1. This should solve the issue.

**EDITED**

To find the small names of your directories -

Open a command prompt go to your parent directory and fire this command - DIR/X and you will get list of small names for all of your directories. Replace any name with space with the name you get here.

Comment: "E:\Androidsw\android-sdk-windows" this is my sdk path.

Answer (score 0):

I got the following error in Windows 7 with Android Emulator
invalid command-line parameter:Files.

From Stack Overflow Suggestion I tried the mlink suggestion as follows:

C:>mklink /D "D:\Android\" "c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk-windows\"

In the eclipse Change the location of Android location.
Help --> Prefrences -> SDK Locatoion to D:\Android
Run an application from eclipse, it will show the output in emulator.
(Note : It is not possible to start emulator from SDK Manager Directly)

[www.rajaramsystems.com/blog](http://www.rajaramsystems.com/blog)